# Autodesk Eagle multichannel schematic

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

I'm making a multichannel system. I have a channel layout and schematic in a design block. I was wondering if there's a way to show the channel in the system schematic as a module or a simple block(symbol?) instead of it's whole schematic. It just makes the schematic way bigger than it has to be.

Comment: Yes there is a way. There are so called design blocks. You can also do prerouting and add the new channel as finished device in the shematic and layout. Just google it. https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/whats-new-in-autodesk-eagle-modular-design-blocks/

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Have you read what I wrote? If I was not clear enough in the post please say it. I already said that I was using design blocks but I would prefer showing the channels in a more compact way. The link you posted doesn't really help me with that. Thanks anyway though.